# Merging 2 branches that have the same commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-merge

I have the following scenario:

```
master

test_1 (branch from master) with commit X updated with --amend

test_2 (branch from test_1) with original commit X and a new commit Y.
```

I am new to git and i made a mistake when i created the second branch. That branch was supposed to be from master, instead it's a branch of **`test_1`** after i already done a `commit X` on **`test_1`**. I worked on **`test_2`** (`commit Y`) and meanwhile i had to modify something for the `commit X` done on **`test_1`**.

How should i proceed in merging these branches into master in a way that i don't have to create new commits or having to solve the conflict between `commit X` from **`test_2`** and `commit X updated` from **`test_1`** (a lot of files changed)? Also, `commit Y` is done on different files than `commit X`.

EDIT: At first i thought about creating a new branch from master and copying the files done for commit Y and merge with this branch, but i want to know if there is a "cleaner" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cherry-pick` your changes from `test_1` and `test_2` branch. In order to get the changes in `master`, switch to `master` branch and,

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash-of-X> <commit-hash-of-Y>
```

Whenever there is an `amend` the hash gets changed. The commit hash of X in `test_1` will be different from that of `test_2`. So pick X from `test_1` and Y from `test_2`

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Thanks a lot.